# How to properly open pipe(s) with moose?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, moose

I'm still new to moose, but it has me drooling!  Below is a simplified version of what I would like to do: generate object dependent input files that may be used to run an external program.  These external programs can be intensive computationally, and I will process the output back into the objects many times each for many objects (as a function of some external parameter tweaking).  The module below works (I think), but there may be better/cleaner ways to do this.  What is the proper way to do this?  Since all these objects live in their own little world, it seems as though I should be able to run batches of these in parallel to efficiently chomp through the collection of objects.  Any tips for this!??

```
{
package input_genrun;                                              
use Moose;                                                         
use IO::Pipe;                                                      
use FileHandle;                                                    

has 'name', is => 'ro', isa =>'Str';
has 'exe'      => (                 
                    is  => 'ro',    
                    isa => 'Str',   
                    default => '/usr/local/bin/bar',
                  );
has 'inp_fh'   => (
                    is => 'rw',
                    isa=> 'FileHandle',
                    default => sub {
                      my $handle = FileHandle->new;
                      return $handle;
                    }
                  );
has 'out_fh'   => (
                    is => 'rw',
                    isa=> 'IO::Pipe',
                    default => sub {
                      my $handle = IO::Pipe->new;
                      return $handle;
                    }
                  );

sub inp_wrt
{
  my ($self,$object) = @_;
  my $filename = $object->name() . ".inp";
  my $fh = FileHandle->new;
  $fh->open(">" . $filename);
  print $fh "foo \n";
  print $fh "bar \n";
  $fh->close;
}

sub run
{
  my ($self, $object) = @_;
  my $name = $object->name() . ".inp";
  my $exe = $self->exe;
  my $command = $self->exe . " $name";
  $self->out_fh()->reader($command);
  return($self->out_fh());
}

} 

my $l = input_genrun->new(name=> 'foo_l',exe=> 'wc');
my $m = input_genrun->new(name=> 'foo_m',exe=> 'cat');
my $n = input_genrun->new(name=> 'foo_n',exe=> 'tac');

$l->inp_wrt($l);
$m->inp_wrt($m);
$n->inp_wrt($n);

my $pipe_l = $l->run($l);
my $pipe_m = $m->run($m);
my $pipe_n = $n->run($n);

while (<$pipe_l>){
  print "from_l: $_";
}
while (<$pipe_m>){
  print "from_m: $_";
}
while (<$pipe_n>){
  print "from_n: $_";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by taking a look at `MooseX::Workers` which abstracts around `POE::Wheel::Run` to solve this same problem. Failing that I'd look at a number of the other asynchronous job handlers out there (`Parallel::Fork`, `Proc::Simple::Async`, `Gearman`, etc.) before really going to tackle implementing the wheel again.

If nothing else they'll give you a good idea of what has been done before in this space.